# SSRS Parameters in Query Code decay performance?

Tags: reporting-services

i'm building some Report with SQL Report Services. I've this query:

```
select 
FromPhone.PhoneUri as FROM_PHONE, 
Agente.UserUri as AGENTE,
IVRSession.InviteTime as INVITE,
AgenteSession.ResponseTime as RESPONSE_TIME, 
AgenteSession.SessionEndTime AS END_TIME,
DATEDIFF(SECOND,AgenteSession.ResponseTime, AgenteSession.SessionEndTime) as DURATA, 
DATEDIFF(SECOND,IVRSession.InviteTime, AgenteSession.ResponseTime) as ATTESA,
AgenteSession.ResponseCode as RESPONSE_CODE

from 
SessionDetails as IVRSession

join VoipDetails on IVRSession.SessionIdTime = VoipDetails.SessionIdTime and    IVRSession.SessionIdSeq = VoipDetails.SessionIdSeq
left outer join Phones as FromPhone on FromPhone.PhoneId = VoipDetails.FromNumberId
left outer join Phones as ConnectedPhone on ConnectedPhone.PhoneId = VoipDetails.ConnectedNumberId

join SessionDetails as AgenteSession on AgenteSession.ReplacesDialogIdTime = IVRSession.SessionIdTime and IVRSession.SessionIdSeq = AgenteSession.ReplacesDialogIdSeq


left outer join Users as User1 on User1.UserId = IVRSession.User1Id
left outer join Users as User2 on User2.UserId = IVRSession.User2Id
left outer join Users as Agente on Agente.UserId = AgenteSession.User1Id


left outer join ClientVersions as Client1Version on Client1Version.VersionId = IVRSession.User1ClientVerId
left outer join ClientVersions as Client2Version on Client2Version.VersionId = IVRSession.User2ClientVerId

    where


(Client1Version.ClientType = 1024 or Client2Version.ClientType = 1024) and
User2.UserUri = 'ivr0679071new@methodo.it' and
IVRSession.InviteTime > '15/01/2014' and IVRSession.InviteTime < '20/02/2014'
```

In this form all works fine but...
if i use two SSRS parameter (@DataDa and @DataA) instead of the Strings in

```
IVRSession.InviteTime > '15/01/2014' and IVRSession.InviteTime < '20/02/2014'
```

The result time its reeeeeally more. Something like > 1 minute

Why this Behaviour???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be suffering from parameter sniffing.  See here for one explanation, though you can find a lot of information about this around the web - https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/parameter-sniffing/

Comment: Thanks u for the answer but i dont have a stored procedure, just a normal query